# How to force calling __getitem__ using items() and values() in dict inheritance in python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I use python3.7 and for some application create a class inherited from a `dict`, but have a problem to implement `items()` and `values()` methods to made it work correctly. This class overrides many methods, but here I placed a very simplified example just to illustrate exact problem:

```
class MyFunction:
    def __call__(self):
        return 5

class MyDict(dict):
    def __getitem__(self, key):
        item = super().__getitem__(key)
        if isinstance(item, MyFunction):
            return item()
        else:
            return item

    def get(self, key, default=None):
        if self.__contains__(key):
            return self.__getitem__(key)
        if isinstance(default, MyFunction):
            return default()
        return default

    # def __copy__(self):
    #     return type(self)(self)
    # 
    # def copy(self):
    #     return self.__copy__()

    # def __iter__(self):
    #     return super().__iter__()


d = MyDict(a=MyFunction(), b=3)
```

I want than I get a value by key instances of `MyFunction` be called. This works well:

```
for k in d:
    print(k, d[k])
```

and prints the expected output:

```
a 5
b 3
```

But these two do not:

```
for v in d.values():
    print(v)

for k, v in d.items():
    print(k, v)
```

They print the function's repr.

**How can I achive them to call `__getitem__`?**

**Remark**: It can be some kind of `dict` built-in class optimization (I would like to not inherit form `UserDict` or `Mapping`). For example if I uncomment:

```
def  __iter__(self):
     return super().__iter__()
```

The calls:

```
new_d = d.copy()
new_d = dict(d)
new_d = dict(**d)
```

will call the `__getitem__`

Comment: "Remark: It can be some kind of dict built-in class optimization (I would like to not inherit form UserDict or Mapping" Why? Inheriting from `dict` won't do what you want it to do, i.e., use your implementation of `__getitem__` for other operations.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga To have some methods more optimized if it possible, and to pass checks isinstance(obj, dict)

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga UserDict also calls all methods in __init__. In my project I have a problem I override __setattr__ in descendant class and it calls it in the inherited when create instance variables. It breaks everything. I need to create a local class, change working class and analyze it in base and descendant classes. They all should be aware. Dict base doen't do that.

Comment: Can you provide a more fleshed out example of what you mean about `__setattr__`?

Answer (score 1):

According to the [Python documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#special-method-names), accessing a dict-like object with the `d[k]` syntax is just syntactic sugar for `d.__getitem__(k)`.

However, as you discovered, the default implementation of `values()` and `items()` do not call `__getitem__()` *at all*. If you want them to, you'll have to implement them yourself.

Here is an implementation that hopefully does what you want:

```
class MyFunction:
    def __call__(self):
        return 5

class MyDict(dict):
    def __getitem__(self, key):
        item = super().__getitem__(key)
        if isinstance(item, MyFunction):
            return item()
        else:
            return item

    def values(self):
        for k in self:
            yield(self[k])

    def items(self):
        for k in self:
            yield(k, self[k])

    def get(self, key, default=None):
        try:
            return self[key]
        except KeyError:
            return default

d = MyDict(a=MyFunction(), b=3)

for k in d:
    print(d.get(k))

for v in d.values():
    print(v)

for k, v in d.items():
    print(k, v)
```

This is the output:

```
5
3
5
3
a 5
b 3
```

Comment: Note, this *breaks* `.items` and `values`, which should return dict-views, not generators.